# is it possible to rewrite these cycles with map?

Tags: python, jython

is it somehow possible to rewrite this tricky dict-function calls (pythonic "cases"..) in cycle with "map" ?

There are some java-functions calls , first I used "if-elif" statements , then decided to use dict , as you can see , I tried use dict without exceptions.

I want to rewrite "for" cycle with mapping "dict"-calls onto column iterator . Is it possible ?

```
type_resolver={'java.lang.String' : set.getString,
               'java.lang.Integer' : set.getInt, 
               #'java.lang.util.Date' : lambda x: None,#set.getTimestamp,
               'java.lang.Short' : set.getShort,
               #'java.util.Collection': lambda x: None,
               #'java.util.Date': lambda x: None,
               #'boolean': lambda x: None
}

while set.next():                     
    for column in COLUMNS:
        try:
            data=type_resolver[STRCT[column]](column)
        except KeyError:
            data=None
        DATAR[column].append(data)
```

Comment: I've tried to edit out as much unnecessary code as possible, but the fact remains that you're appending to different lists based on the value of `column`. That makes it hard to tell whether the `for` loop can be replaced by something simpler.

Comment: Why you want to do that? Maybe you could simplify a bit the code using `get`: `data = type_resolver.get(STRCT[column], lambda x: None)(column)` and remove the `try... except`.
I want to stress that `map` is a **functional** feature. Functional languages avoid side-effects as much as possible, while you want(I think) to use this functional feature with the only intent of applying side-effects more than once. This kind of combinations usually don't work well and lead to ugly code.

Comment: Those while-for cycles are kind of bottlenecks at my code. I read , that using map much more efficient , than use "for" cycle .

I think, you're right Bakuriu , too much different java functions for one mapping statement =| Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using `get` instead of checking for an `KeyError` helps:

```
for column in COLUMNS:
    DATAR[column].append(type_resol.get(STRCT[column], lambda x: None))(column))
```

You can also put it one line but is maybe already too long:

```
[DATAR[column].append(type_resol.get(STRCT[column], lambda x: None))(column)) 
 for column in COLUMN]
```

Furthermore, the last variation throws away the list because it is full of `None`. This can be misleading. You need two lines anyway. So just use the first solution.

Comment: This doesn't work. When the key is not present `get` returns `None` which would raise a `TypeError` since you are trying to call it. That's why in my comment I wrote `get(..., lambda x: None)(column)`.
Also, the OP was interested in using `map`, not list-comprehensions and using `map` it becomes `map(lambda col: DATAR[col].append(type_resolver.get(STRCT[col], lambda x:None)(col)), COLUMNS)`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Modified my solution.